# Kotlin- Single instance of a non-singleton class?

Tags: kotlin

I was doing some experiments with Kotlin and I was playing with singleton patterns. I wanted to persist a single instance of a `Database` object. Just like in Java, I thought I'd wrap a singleton around it.

```
import com.github.davidmoten.rx.jdbc.ConnectionProviderFromUrl
import com.github.davidmoten.rx.jdbc.Database

object DbManager {
    val database : Database =
            Database.from(ConnectionProviderFromUrl("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Thomas/OneDrive/Data/finance_rx.db").get())
}
```

What surprised me however is there seems to be no built-in way to compile getters for it (like properties for a class). It was just straight up exposing that `database` property to the world without any encapsulation, which I did not want.

I could just make it private and explicitly make my own getter (but I'm looking at Kotlin because I'm passionate about being lazy). However, I think I stumbled on another way to do this.

I could create a Kotlin file and declare a private variable and a public function to encapsulate and expose it safely, without putting it in any class or singleton at all!

```
import com.github.davidmoten.rx.jdbc.ConnectionProviderFromUrl
import com.github.davidmoten.rx.jdbc.Database

private val database : Database =
        Database.from(ConnectionProviderFromUrl("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/Thomas/OneDrive/Data/finance_rx.db").get())

fun db(): Database = database;
```

The thing is it just feels way too easy. I feel like I'm doing something bad. But at the same time this makes sense. Nobody likes calling `MySingleton.getInstance().getDb()` a hundred times. Is this pattern I discovered valid and not an anti-pattern?

Also, is there any way to compile getters and encapsulate final properties on the singleton? Or do I implement those methods myself?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is this pattern I discovered valid and not an anti-pattern?

Yes, it's a valid pattern

> Also, is there any way to compile getters and encapsulate final properties on the singleton? Or do I implement those methods myself?

Kotlin properties are not just fields: they already have getters generated for them, so having `database` and `db()` is no better than just `database`.

If you need to change the behavior of the property later without recompiling the clients, you can write a custom getter:

```
val database: Database
    get() = ...
```

This will simply change the body of the getter that is otherwise automatically generated for you

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrey, I was confused because I was accessing the Kotlin class from Java code (which was showing explicit getters for interoperability). I was expecting it to the same thing when accessing it in straight Kotlin. I get it now, it's just like C#.

Comment: On a side note, thanks again for putting together this great language. This is everything and more of what I wanted Java to be (especially coming from C# as my first language).